# fmemopen gives a Valgrind error

Tags: c, stdio

I have the following code:

```
char *filedata;
FILE *f;
filedata = malloc(3);
if (filedata == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
memcpy(filedata, "foo", 3);
f = fmemopen(filedata, 3, "r");
if (f == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
fclose(f);
free(filedata);
```

Now, when I execute this with Valgrind, I get the following error:

```
==32454== Invalid read of size 1
==32454==    at 0x4006D33: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:284)
==32454==    by 0x855B7E: fmemopen (fmemopen.c:246)
==32454==    by 0x80485BF: main (in /home/tilli/memopen/a.out)
==32454==  Address 0x402502b is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==32454==    at 0x4005BDC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==32454==    by 0x8048548: main (in /home/tilli/memopen/a.out)
```

It seems like `fmemopen` is doing an `strlen()` for the argument I passed to it. However, the manual page says that the buffer argument to `fmemopen` can be a string or a memory buffer (so it doesn't have to be `'\0'`-terminated). Furthermore, it says that the argument must be at least `size` bytes long, which it is.

What is wrong here? Have I just a found a bug in the library function `fmemopen`? Am I correct that in extreme cases this bug could crash a program using `fmemopen` if the `strlen` doesn't find a `'\0'` terminator but instead continues to read unmapped memory?

I'm running Fedora release 12.

Comment: What happens if instead of `memcpy(filedata, "foo", 3);` you do a `strcpy(filedata, "fo");` ?

Comment: If I do `strcpy(filedata, "fo");` then the problem disappears as you could deduce from the backtrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual it looks like the `\0` is used as EOF marker for stream buffers unless the mode includes a `b`. This explains why a strlen() would be used to locate the EOF.

From man fmemopen:

> The argument mode is the same as for fopen(3).  If mode specifies an append mode, then the initial file position
>    is  set  to the location of the first null byte ('\0') in the buffer; otherwise the initial file position is set
>    to the start of the buffer.  Since glibc 2.9, the letter 'b' may be specified as the second character  in  mode.
>   This provides "binary" mode: writes don't implicitly add a terminating null byte, and fseek(3) SEEK_END is rela‐
>   tive to the end of the buffer (i.e., the value specified by the size argument), rather than the  current  string
>   length.

However, in the same man we can read :

> In a stream opened for reading, null bytes ('\0') in the buffer do not cause read operations to return  an  end-
>          of-file  indication.   A read from the buffer will only indicate end-of-file when the file pointer advances size
>          bytes past the start of the buffer.

So you might have found a bug.

Comment: This sounds like a good theory until you try it. I tested the mode "rb" also, and unfortunately the error doesn't seem to disappear. So, if I understand the fmemopen man page correctly, I should use "b" if I have a raw memory block instead of a string. But, the problem itself doesn't disappear with "b". My manual page too has the glibc 2.9 mention, so I assume this isn't due to using a too old version of glibc.

Comment: Looking at the source code here I found with google [http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~islene/2s2008-mo806/libc/libio/fmemopen.c] there is indeed a strlen(c->buffer) performed even if the file is open for reading, and even with binary mode. This doesn't match the man specification.

Answer (score 2):

Using gcc 5.3.1 and valgrind 3.11.0 on Ubuntu 16.04, valgrind does not report any error. So it seems, that the bug has been fixed in the meantime.